# Python code to read a file and replace multiple occurrence of a charterer to a single character

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file in which values are as follows
945678##########Rakesh######12365###########doc###delhi

## 234566########vipul#########964532#########dac#######mumbai

I want to replace all # with single #.

Any suggestion to clean the data so that single # will act as a delimiter.

Comment: Hello,
You should add a code example of what you've tried so far and explain where you're stuck

Comment: I have used linux command as 

sed -i 's/#*/#/g' <file-name> but in the output it has inserted # after every character in every line inside the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression:

```
import re
string = '945678##########Rakesh######12365###########doc###delhi'
new_string = re.sub(r'#+','#',string)
print(new_string)
```

output:

> 945678#Rakesh#12365#doc#delhi

Comment: what if i have 500 lines in a file. i cant hardcore the string. Please help me with other way.

Comment: @Ashish Mathur I'm sorry I can't follow you. Is there any difference if there are 500 lines in a file? You just call the `re.sub()` function in a `for` loop. Or could you please make your question more explict?